# Connect switch on router ISP and lose internet connection one of the pc's

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

I connected a switch on my router provider ISP. I have the cable between this router and my switch. On this switch I have connected two pc, with Linux obvious :)
When I connected one pc with the cable, provide router ISP, I can access Internet. But when I connected the second pc I lose the internet connection on pc but I won the internet connection on another pc. Basically I can't have two pc with internet connection within the same networking.

One of the pc has IP static and the first, which loses internet connection when I connect the second pc, the second pc has Automatic DHCP. But despite losing the internet connection I can access the second PC. Therefore I have networking between all pc on my networking but on the first pc I lose internet connection when connected the second pc in networking (note: the second pc has internet connection despite the first lose).

How can I resolve this problem? Which configuration might I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DHCP on both PC and try again.
Does your ISP allows to connect multiple clients to the router provided by them? Some ISP only allows a single IP through their router/modem. If that is the case you will have to plug the cable from ISP router to a new **router** and connect the devices to the new router(not an ordinary switch).

So first try by using DHCP on both systems.

If that doesn't work try **different static IP** on both systems.

If that too doesn't work check if **NAT**(Network Address Translation) is enabled on router or does it **support** such feature.

If that doesn't work, then please **replace the switch with a new router**. This will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks your reply,

But How I should configure the networking with two pc and switch? I will start to that and  after I will bother with the connection the cable provider my router (the isp - internet connection) .

I put this question because I configure ip static on my pc and on the raspberry. When I execute ssh user@ip_raspberry the command was very slow to respond. 

Thanks

Comment: @EdgarOliveira If you have a switch and you are on the same subnet, then networking is as simple as connecting the cables to switch. Same subnet means your ip should look like this PC1: 192.168.1.50, PC2: 192.168.1.51 The first 3 segments of IP mst be same for all systems

Comment: Just solve this problem. This is a stupid error, on my opinion. Basically when I connected the PC1 on switch I lost internet because forgot it configuration "DNS servers". First mistake! Set this parameter on PC1 and I could browser on the internet. The second mistake was when I disconnect the cable provider the router, the signal (between PC1 and PC2) stayed very slow. How did I resolve this? Simple, when I disconnected the router cable I need also disconnect and connect the cable the PC2. I don't know because this is necessary, but this is the only option that I discovered.